# Apex Gantt charts vs Calendar

Tags: sql, plsql, calendar, oracle-apex, gantt-chart

I am somewhat struggling with a project that I have set myself to do:

I am attempting to create a Web application for ServiceDesk work schedule. The app would show a schedule on a principle of week/month/year with the option to change view and enable users to see a spreadsheet like schedule for their daily assignments. A similar view as such, just maybe less detailed.

[image]

I am trying to build it in Oracle Apex. Now I have narrowed it down to 2 possibilities in terms of layout: either I use calendar, in which the layout would be slightly different and would basically have to show each task with details of who and what, or I go for Gantt chart and make it so that the left side shows names of the employees and the upper side shows time in days/months/years.

What I am struggling with is whether one or the other is the right way to go. I am trying not to make it too complicated for the administrator to make changes (at the moment, the work schedule is in excel spreadsheet, updated every month) as that would be counterproductive and could make it worse to use than excel. Also, the reason why I chose Apex is the fast that the company I work for actually uses apex in a lot of the projects and would be a bit easier to integrate with the rest of the systems already in play.

Any tips or guidelines to follow would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To start, I don't think you want to use a Calendar region, as there are a lot of constraints on it. It's not clear to me what the codes are in the boxes in the middle (yellow/red/green/blue backgrounds)? Finally, do you want the administrator to be able to drag-n-drop the cells from one person or day to another? How will they interact with the page?

Comment: Absolutely a valid point - that is exactly why i am asking. From my, rather limited i admit, knowledge of apex chart priciples, it is rather difficult to change the values inside a chart other than changing the table. The idea is that the fields inside - doesnt matter the color or label- be as much customizable as possible via direct input. The fields are basically shift schedules - so what each person does that day. So it would make sense that the fields be editable via drag n drop or at least via some hovering field. If i understand th apex chart system, that isnt possible?

Answer (score 0):

Jervis,

Based on your comment:

- Apex Calendar region is not appropriate here, as the ability to customize it is **very limited**. You couldn't even get it to show the 30 days shown in your mock-up.
- I don't think Apex Charts would allow the formatting you're looking for either.

You need a grid region of some sort where you can arrange and style it. You can try an **Apex Interactive Grid** region. That doesn't include drag-n-drop functionality out of the box and I don't know of a free plug-in adds that functionality. That will probably do the basics of what you want

**If you can pay** for a commercial Apex framework, I'd recommend the FOEX Enterprise framework, which adds a ton of functionality and interactivity, including  editable grids that you can drag-n-drop.  It's not cheap (per-developer licensing) and there's a learning curve because it's a different way of doing Apex, but it's a very solid product and you can buy consulting time from them.

(I'm a FOEX customer, not an employee or a shill)